# Simply validate email in laravel without creating validator

Tags: laravel

How can I simply validate an email in laravel, without creating a validator?

```
Validator::email($email)
```

does not work

Comment: Im not sure it provides prebuilt static function like that

Comment: Whats the issue with creating a validator?

Comment: use `$this->validate($request, array('email' => 'email',));` in your store function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By laravel [ref](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation)

We can do like this `Validator::make(['email' => $email], [ 'email' => 'email'])`

**OR**

By using laravel helper we can do like this

```
 validator(['email' => $email], ['email' => 'required|email']);
```

**OR**

Edit: We can further simplefy this by using macro

Add this in Service provider

```
$this
            ->app
            ->make(Validator::class)
            ->macro('email', function ($email) {
                return Validator::make(['email' => $email], [ 'email' => 'email'])
            });
```

And now we can use like this

```
Validator::email($email)
```

Note: Not test this just throwing some idea we can do this way.

Comment: I was hoping I can call the validator functions directly without making a service, but hanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The BaseController uses ValidatesRequests trait so in the controller you can do...

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'email',
]);
//
}
```

Comment: I am not in a  request

Answer (score 1):

How about using PHP `filter_var`?
https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

```php
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses the [egulias/email-validator](https://github.com/egulias/EmailValidator) package to validate emails. So you can use it without creating the validator instance. For example:

```
    use Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator;
    use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\DNSCheckValidation;
    use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\Extra\SpoofCheckValidation;
    use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\MultipleValidationWithAnd;
    use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\NoRFCWarningsValidation;
    use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\RFCValidation;

    //...

    $email = "example@gmail.com";

    //choose validators you want here
    $validations = [
        new NoRFCWarningsValidation(), //strict
        new DNSCheckValidation(), //dns
        new SpoofCheckValidation(), //spoof
        new FilterEmailValidation(), //filter
        FilterEmailValidation::unicode(), //filter_unicode,
        new RFCValidation(), //rfc
    ];

    $isValid = (new EmailValidator)->isValid($email, new MultipleValidationWithAnd($validations));
```

The original Laravel 10 email validation code is located in `Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\ValidatesAttributes::validateEmail()`